# DataGridView Control In C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

Hello Everyone, 
I  am trying to add my database to the "DatagridView, but when I do add a record and click the delete and saved button, it throws this error "System.InvalidOperationException" and the record isn't deleted. Is there any reason for this? I follow the appropriate steps in adding the database to the form, but I keep getting this error.

This is my connection to the database:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Technician_Maintenace_Project_18_1.Properties.Settings.TechSupport_DataConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Users\Momo Johnson\Desktop\TechSupport\TechSupport_Data.MDF&quot;;Integrated    Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is code generated by visual studios

```
namespace Technician_Maintenace_Project_18_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void techniciansBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.techniciansBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.techSupport_DataDataSet);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'techSupport_DataDataSet.Technicians' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.techniciansTableAdapter.Fill(this.techSupport_DataDataSet.Technicians);
        }
    }
}
```

FYI. The database is saving any record I add, but it's not deleting the record when I press the delete key and saved.

Comment: I don't see any Click event for the Delete button.

Comment: I am using the datagridview  to delete a row. Doesn't the x button on the datagridview delete a row?

Comment: is it the same if you select a whole row and press the delete key? Might be because no primary key is selected.